# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string'?

Tags: typescript2.0

Looking at some code in VS and this shows a red line under 'length', with a message in the title. Using typescript 2.2.2

What is going on?

```
addFilterTag = (value:string, type: Enums.FilterType): void  =>
{
   if (value.length > 0)
   {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: Yes I do have it installed

Comment: Try disabling it, Ive had several false error flags using it with TypeScript.  Also make sure your TypeScript settings in ReSharper point to 2.2

Comment: O it is disabled, it is just not usable to have it turned on all the time as it is slowwwww.

Comment: If you are using MSBuild, try switching to a tsconfig.json.  Ive had issues, to say the least with VS2017 and TypeScript:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589319/vs2017-publishing-error-when-compiling-typescript

Comment: 2015 with tsconfig. I also have issues that it cannot find some modules if I am using "paths" matching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620918/typescript-path-mapping-not-working-in-visual-studio